# Copy/duplicate field values on add/edit (plone/dexterity)

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type (container) where I have two custom fields for a contract start date and end date.

When creating the type I’d like the end date to be used also for the Plone “expiration date”.

How do I copy the Date over to the Expiration Date field?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 approaches to solve this: the first is to use the standard **expires** field directly instead of your custom end date field; you could have an issue if you want to override the label/description of it, as you will have no way (AFAIK) to change them only for your domain.

the second one could be to override the standard **expires** field and make its getter method return the value of your custom end date field.

check the following documentation:

- [Plone and Dexterity: Working with computed fields](http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/04/plone-and-dexterity-working-with-computed-fields/)
- [Plone Developer Documentation: Behaviors](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/behaviors/index.html)
- [Medatada definitions inside plone.app.dexterity](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/blob/master/plone/app/dexterity/behaviors/metadata.py)